# What code can I use in SAS to create new variable B which containing the first three characters of variable A only under a specific condition?

Tags: sas

Here is a sample of data points of variable A:  `P8760, B97097, P32417, 082709, 7290`

I'd like to create variable B which only has the first three characters of variable A. I do this by using code:

```
/******Create new variable B ******/

data want;
  set have;
 Length
  B $3; 
  B = A; 
run;
```

However, I only want to create variable B where the first character of variable A equals the letter P. So the final variable B would only contain data points: P87 & P32

How can I accomplish creating variable B under this condition in SAS?

Comment: Variable do not contain "data points".  The variable has a value on each observation of the dataset. Do you mean that the dataset WANT will only contain those observations?  Or do you mean that you just want variable B to be missing for the other observations?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `LIKE` operator in `WHERE` statement:

```
data want;
   set have;
   where A LIKE 'P%'; /*%-Wildcard Character*/
   B=substr(A,1,3);
run;
```

Or using `regex`:

```
data want;
   set have;
   if prxmatch("/P.*/",A) then do;
      B=substr(A,1,3);
      output;
   end;
run;
```